# Intellij IDEA Tomcat Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, tomcat7, java-7, intellij-14

I am using Intellij Ultimate edition 14.0.2

Working on a Java project using Maven as my build tool.

We are getting this error when attempting to launch my project via Tomcat server.

> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop,
>   reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

Have attempted, mvn clean install, rebuild the project in intellij, open and shut down intellij.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the feedback everyone. I ended up editing my host file to reference my computer name. I have not been able to recreate the issue.

Solved for now.

Comment: this one http://biomedicalontologies.com/2012/11/14/fixing-java-net-local-host-name-unknown-error-on-mac-os-x/ is only that helped me in my case. os x, IntelliJ 14, tomcat 8

Comment: @CalebKing3, whats mean of `editing my host file to reference my computer name` ??

Comment: @aircraft if you go into terminal and start at `root` then `sudo vim /etc/hosts` then you will see your host file. I have localhost set to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me, i experienced the same error at some point;

1. Click on Tomcat in your IntelliJ, and then Edit Configurations. On the Startup/Configuration tab, click Debug, on debug properties i have added 52112 as Port number and it worked.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Z5b.png)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is rarely ambiguous. You should check connection between IntelliJ IDEA and Tomcat Server. Checklist like marked points:
+ Configure Tomcat Server.
+ Before launch application server, you must configure to add artifacts to application sever.
+ Turn off other Tomcat server(s) in your computer (localhost)
etc.

[image]

Comment: Hello Do Nhu Vy. My configuration is correct. The error only seems to occur if I was running tomcat and my mac goes to sleep. Then it gets stuck. The only solution which is not ideal, is shutting down the computer multiple times before it works again.

Comment: this the does not hep the slightest bit this is an awful answer.