# IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3 Ultimate: Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, war, jmx

I'm trying to run an exploded war, to deploy it from IDEA Ultimate through a `local Tomcat Server run configuration`. When I start the main artifact I'm always getting this error.

I looked at other threads in here, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037327/intellij-idea-tomcat-application-server-was-not-connected-before-run-configurati), and I think I have a different problem. After IDEA reports failure, Tomcat is up and running and I can connect without a problem to `localhost:1099` with Java VisualVM.

Regarding [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068977/intellij-cant-start-simple-web-application-unable-to-ping-server-at-localhost), I'm running a Debian 6 x64 system and localhost refers to 127.0.0.1 without issue. Also Java VisualVM works, so I'm confident I'm not having this problem. The tomcat distribution I'm using is `apache-tomcat-6.0.43`.

There was a different problem I read about on the [JetBrains trac](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88167) and at least the `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1` VM option specified there didn't help.

According to [this thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2013-October/006093.html) (yet I'm obviously not running OS X) there might be an issue with JDK and the JMX interface, somewhere between 1.7.0_40 and 1.7.0_60. I have my problem though with 1.7.0_53, 1.7.0_23 and 1.7.0_80. And JMX probably works fine in my case (as I said above, VisualVM connects to the tomcat launched and "forgotten" by IDEA at `localhost:1099` without failure).

Any clue about fixing this error?

Comment: did you find any solution ? It just started happening suddenly after two restarts of tomcat through Idea ultimate.

Comment: for me, it came to out to be an `&` in one of the `-D` param values.

Comment: heh, nice @coding_idiot, i simply gave up trying to launch from the IDE

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i put a jar into ..\domains\domain_name\lib folder (weblogic)

It is interesting that not all jar files lead to this problem.

Anyway, after i deleted the jar file (in my situation it was httpclient-4.4.1.jar) error has gone away.