# IntelliJ Ultimate cannot open open Tomcat Web Application

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Only ultimate has web application support so that's out of the way.

I am trying to start open up my web app via tomcat something which I do successfully on the same machine on netbeans with next to no configuration.

What is the step by step guide to getting this to work here are several of my attempts:
[image: both tomcat and tomcat EE added]
both are added for good measure[image: all possible combinations]

all possible combinations with EE and non EE remote and local.

none of which work.

I've done this: [Cannot run/debug jsp page from within IntelliJ using Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346328/cannot-run-debug-jsp-page-from-within-intellij-using-tomcat-server)

checked this: [Intellij IDEA Tomcat Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037327/intellij-idea-tomcat-application-server-was-not-connected-before-run-configurati)

done this: [IntelliJ, can't start simple web application: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068977/intellij-cant-start-simple-web-application-unable-to-ping-server-at-localhost)

but nothing gives way.

Running tomcat local (first thing I tried and what I would have bet on. Chrome actually opens but the page cannot be found.)

[image: chrome]

Which is more promising because tomcat is actually found if I manually navigate to index.jsp:

[image: tomcatworking]

but no other URL works. not the project path, not its path plus index.jsp:

[image]

Running tomcat remote:

[image: running tomcat remote]

same for TomEE local runs but fails to find webpage. remote fails to run with same error message. though unless the terminology is seriously *** up (I've seen app makers go this far before) what I want is local.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe only possible way to have a functioning Tomcat and webapp project under intellij is to first create a new project via the wizard and select web app.

the guide here is to be followed exactly : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/enabling-web-application-support.html

any deveation and trying to convert an existing project into a web app is not supported.

(I'm sorry for anyone who feels differently but just try you'll see)

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected an artifact in the Deployment tab? If not add an artifact. After that, you should be able to request your site.

So you need to do: Open the configuration -> go to the Deployment tab -> add the artifact you want to deploy on the tomcat.

Restart tomcat and done you should be able to request your side :)

Comment: what artifact??

Comment: When you configured the artifact building you'll be able to add the artifact to that tab. (Open module settings -> artifacts -> add web application) So you will get an artifact after building that is able to be deployed on the tomcat.

Comment: I see what you mean but this breaks down at any point in the process as there is no way to bridge the missing pieces. Intellij does not provide a way to fill out the missing pieces of the puzzle afterwards. The only accepted way of having a functional setup is to create a web project from the wizard with tomcat set there. it's annoying because it means you can't turn a github roject into a webap but the opposite is true.